# set up VPN server to share internet connection

Tags: android, internet, vpn

In my university, the wifi signal covers anywhere in the campus.

However, an internet client software is needed for users to login before the internet connection is available. And there are no such client in my android cellphone.

So, is it possible to set up an VPN server using my PC(windows 7, which has the access to the Internet), and then connect to it using my android cellphone to get the access to the Internet?

P.S. I have **no access** to the routers because it is controlled by the univerisity.

Comment: Have you tried to make an adHoc in your laptop and connect to it from your mobile..?

Comment: you mean setting up wifi using the laptop? It's workable..but it is impossible to take my laptop with me all the time..

Answer (score 0):

Use the software Connectify-Me to create a hot-spot, using this you can share your internet through different interfaces.